# Is Validation called before or after Coercion when setting a DependencyProperty value?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I created a simple class with a DependencyProperty. When setting the value, I observe that ValidateValueCallback is called before CoerceValueCallback.

On [wpftutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/How+does+a+DependencyProperty+resolve+its+value.htm) and in other books, it is stated that coercion is called before validation.

Answer (score 2):

3.5sp1 here.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) seems to imply that validation occurs before coercion. This matches what you have discovered.

I did it myself and `ValidateValueCallback` comes before `CoerceValueCallback`. I even read source in [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) and confirmed the same, although it's hard to follow all that code an know for sure all possible paths.

Interesting. I wonder if it was the other way around in an earlier version.

**Edit:**

Apparently, when you return a different value from the `CoerceValueCallback`, the `ValidateValueCallback` is called again for the new value. Validate-Coerce-Validate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I've observed the same thing. It then seems that validation really does come before coercion. When a new value is set, it is validated. If coercion changes/constraints a value, it has to be validated again. So technically, validation always happens right after a "set," if we view coercion to be just another "set."

I guess the other sites/books are making an assumption, albeit a confusing one, that validation specifically happens after coercion. It seems to happen after any "set."